# Renderizar template en javaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
var alumnos=[
{
    nombre: 'Jesús',
    apellidoP:'Paniagua',
    apellidoM:'Hernández',
    parcial1:6,
    parcial2:5,
    parcial3:10,
},
{
    nombre: 'Mauricio',
    apellidoP:'Salgado',
    apellidoM:'Flores',
    parcial1:8,
    parcial2:10,
    parcial3:9,



},

{
    nombre: 'Diana',
    apellidoP:'López',
    apellidoM:'García',
    parcial1:6,
    parcial2:5,
    parcial3:0,

}


]

const tuNombre=alumnos.map(function(alumno){
    return alumno.nombre
})
//console.log(tuNombre)
const tuApellidoP=alumnos.map((alumno)=>{
     return alumno.apellidoP
})

const tuApellidoM=alumnos.map((alumno)=>{
    return alumno.apellidoM
})

const primeraParcial=alumnos.map((alumno)=>{
    return alumno.parcial1
})

const segundaParcial=alumnos.map((alumno)=>{
    return alumno.parcial2
})

const terceraParcial=alumnos.map((alumno)=>{
    return alumno.parcial3
})
console.log(tuNombre,tuApellidoP,tuApellidoM,primeraParcial,segundaParcial,terceraParcial)

const tuNombre1=tuNombre.forEach((nombre,index)=> {
    console.log(`${index} : ${nombre}`);
})

const tuApellido1=tuApellidoP.forEach((apellidoP,index)=> {
    console.log(`${index} : ${apellidoP}`);
})

const tuApellidoM1=tuApellidoM.forEach((apellidoM,index)=> {
    console.log(`${index} : ${apellidoM}`);
})

const primeraParcial1=primeraParcial.forEach((parcial1,index)=> {
    console.log(`${index} : ${parcial1}`);
})

const segundaParcial1=segundaParcial.forEach((parcial2,index)=> {
    console.log(`${index} : ${parcial2}`);
})

const terceraParcial1=terceraParcial.forEach((parcial3,index)=> {
    console.log(`${index} : ${parcial3}`);
})

const renderizar = `
          <tr><td>Nombre</td>
          <td>Apellido P</td>
          <td>ApellidoM</td>
          <td>Parcial1</td>
          <td>Parcial2</td>
          <td>parcial3</td>
          
          
`;

const renderizar1 =(tuNombre1,tuApellido1,tuApellidoM1,primeraParcial1,segundaParcial1,terceraParcial1)=>{
return 
 `

          <tr>
          <td>${tuNombre1}<td>
          <td>${tuApellido1}<td>
          <td>${tuApellidoM1}<td>
          <td>${primeraParcial1}<td>
          <td>${segundaParcial1}<td>
          <td>${terceraParcial1}<td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>${tuNombre}<td>
          <td>${tuApellidoP}<td>
          <td>${tuApellidoM}<td>
          <td>${primeraParcial}<td>
          <td>${segundaParcial}<td>
          <td>${terceraParcial}<td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>${tuNombre}<td>
          <td>${tuApellidoP}<td>
          <td>${tuApellidoM}<td>
          <td>${primeraParcial}<td>
          <td>${segundaParcial}<td>
          <td>${terceraParcial}<td>

          </tr>
          
          


`;
}
let completo=()=>{
     let tbody=document.querySelector('#myTabla tbody')
     tbody.innerHTML=renderizar1()
    document.querySelector('#myTabla thead').innerHTML=renderizar
}

completo()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Notas</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table table-hover" id="myTabla">
        <thead>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
      </table>


    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="./notas.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

En el código enviado , mi intención es renderizar datos extraidos desde una matriz de objetos , en primer término los datos los extraigo desde la matriz de objetos mediante el método map , luego hago un forEach a cada matriz formada y guardo la  información en una constante . Para finalmente renderizar estos datos con interpolación en template. Pero solamente se renderiza el thead . Solicito una explicación para finalizar mi codigo o bien el código correcto para hacerlo.

la idea es tener este código de plantilla cuando esté con matrices de objetos de mayor envergadura.

Answer (score 0):

Por medio del siguiente código en archivo js se logra renderizar correctamente

```
var alumnos=[
    {
        nombre: "Jesús",
        apellidoP:"Paniagua",
        apellidoM:"Hernández",
        parcial1:6,
        parcial2:5,
        parcial3:10,
    },
    {
        nombre: "Mauricio",
        apellidoP:"Salgado",
        apellidoM:"Flores",
        parcial1:8,
        parcial2:10,
        parcial3:9,
    
    
    
    },
    
    {
        nombre: "Diana",
        apellidoP:"López",
        apellidoM:"García",
        parcial1:6,
        parcial2:5,
        parcial3:0,
    
    }
    
    
    ]
    const renderizar = `
          <tr><td>Nombre</td>
          <td>Apellido P</td>
          <td>ApellidoM</td>
          <td>Parcial1</td>
          <td>Parcial2</td>
          <td>parcial3</td>
          
          
`;
let completo=()=>{
     
    document.querySelector('#myTabla thead').innerHTML=renderizar
}

completo()

const $cuerpoTabla = document.querySelector('#cuerpoTabla')
// recorrer todos los alumnos
const recorrido = alumnos.forEach(alumno =>{
    // crear un <tr>
    const $tr = document.createElement("tr");
    // creamos el <td> de nombre y lo adjuntamos al <tr>
    let $tdNombre = document.createElement("td");
    $tdNombre.textContent=alumno.nombre;
    $tr.appendChild($tdNombre);
    let $tdapellidoP = document.createElement("td");
    $tdapellidoP.textContent=alumno.apellidoP;
    $tr.appendChild($tdapellidoP);
    let $tdapellidoM = document.createElement("td");
    $tdapellidoM.textContent=alumno.apellidoM;
    $tr.appendChild($tdapellidoM);
    let $tdparcial1 = document.createElement("td");
    $tdparcial1.textContent=alumno.parcial1;
    $tr.appendChild($tdparcial1);
    let $tdparcial2 = document.createElement("td");
    $tdparcial2.textContent=alumno.parcial2;
    $tr.appendChild($tdparcial2);
    let $tdparcial3 = document.createElement("td");
    $tdparcial3.textContent=alumno.parcial3;
    $tr.appendChild($tdparcial3);
    //  Finalmente agregamos el tr al cuerpo de la tabla
    $cuerpoTabla.appendChild($tr);
})
console.log(recorrido)
```

Por medio de este código , se observa la tabla. De todos modos, deseo obtener el código por medio de template.